# checking multiple checkboxlist with a click of a button

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have three different checkbox list on my web page. I want to have a checkbox that says "select All" and when that check box is checked then all three checkbox list checkboxes are checked. I was looking at this example that checks one checkbox list by clicking on select button, but I want all three checkbox list checkboxes to be checked in javascript. Below is my code

```
 <asp:CheckBox ID="chkCheckAll" runat="server" Text="Check/Uncheck All"  
                                        Style="font-weight: 700"      CausesValidation="false" oncheckedchanged="chkCheckAll_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true" 
                                          />

   <asp:CheckBoxList ID="chkList_MetricsSeverity" runat="server"   RepeatDirection="Horizontal"
                                                RepeatColumns="3" Width="1060px">
                                            </asp:CheckBoxList>

 <asp:CheckBoxList ID="chkList_MetricsAvgMedian" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal"
                                                RepeatColumns="3" Width="1060px">
                                            </asp:CheckBoxList>

 <asp:CheckBoxList ID="chkList_Counts" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal"
                                                RepeatColumns="3" Width="1060px">
                                            </asp:CheckBoxList>
```

any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what needs to eb done. below is the code

```
  function CheckAll() {


        var chkbx = document.getElementById('<%=chkCheckAll.ClientID %>');

        var chkbxList1 = document.getElementById('<%=chkList_MetricsSeverity.ClientID %>');

        var chkbxList2 = document.getElementById('<%=chkList_MetricsAvgMedian.ClientID %>');

        var chkbxList3 = document.getElementById('<%=chkList_Counts.ClientID %>');
        if (chkbx.checked == true) {
            var chkbxListCount = chkbxList1.getElementsByTagName('input');
            for (var i = 0; i < chkbxListCount.length; i++) {
                chkbxListCount[i].checked = true;
            }
            var chkbxListCount = chkbxList2.getElementsByTagName('input');
            for (var i = 0; i < chkbxListCount.length; i++) {
                chkbxListCount[i].checked = true;
            }
            var chkbxListCount = chkbxList3.getElementsByTagName('input');
            for (var i = 0; i < chkbxListCount.length; i++) {
                chkbxListCount[i].checked = true;
            }
        }
        else {
            var chkbxListCount = chkbxList1.getElementsByTagName('input');
            for (var i = 0; i < chkbxListCount.length; i++) {
                chkbxListCount[i].checked = false;
            }
            var chkbxListCount = chkbxList2.getElementsByTagName('input');
            for (var i = 0; i < chkbxListCount.length; i++) {
                chkbxListCount[i].checked = false;
            }
            var chkbxListCount = chkbxList3.getElementsByTagName('input');
            for (var i = 0; i < chkbxListCount.length; i++) {
                chkbxListCount[i].checked = false;
            }
        } 




    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look [here](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=77)...You can find the way to implement above stuff in both asp.net and javascript way......

Comment: I already saw that article, but it only for one checkbox list. i need to pass the id for multiple checkboxlist in the javascript function. I don't know how to do that.